# Python Changing from single input to list results in error

Tags: python

Could someone explain "how/why" the following error is occurring?

Single input code

```
PASTED_CRM_DATA = "13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607"
URL_LIST = 'https://www.realestate.com.au/property/' + str(PASTED_CRM_DATA.replace(' ', '-').lower()),
```

Results in: *Scraping URL 1 of 1 https://www.realestate.com.au/property/13-hoadley-st-mawson-act-2607*

However when converting to a list

```
PASTED_CRM_DATA = ["13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607",
"13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607"
]
URL_LIST = 'https://www.realestate.com.au/property/' + str(PASTED_CRM_DATA.replace(' ', '-').lower()),
```

Results in: *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'*

I understand the error in theory, but how does one overcome the object not being able to format text inside the list?

Comment: It's not the object's responsibility to format the text.

Comment: Sorry pal, I edited the answer, I misunderstood your main goal of your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replace` is for string, for list you need loop and replace it one by one

```
PASTED_CRM_DATA = ["13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607",
"13 HOADLEY ST MAWSON ACT 2607"]
URL_LIST = ['https://www.realestate.com.au/property/' + x.replace(' ', '-').lower() for x in PASTED_CRM_DATA]

print(URL_LIST)

# ['https://www.realestate.com.au/property/13-hoadley-st-mawson-act-2607', 
#  'https://www.realestate.com.au/property/13-hoadley-st-mawson-act-2607']
```

Answer (score 1):

> Edit

You are converting the list into a string with str, that's why you get the error, you have to make the replace after convert.
 I misunderstood the goal of you code, I correct it to:

```
URL_LIST = ['https://www.realestate.com.au/property/' + endpoint.replace(' ', '-').lower() for endpoint in PASTED_CRM_DATA]
```